Subset a list based on the length of another column in R (to allow turning mismatched-length df into a tibble)
My data has one column with ~40 entries, and all other columns have ~20 entries, and many columns are lists. I need to unlist these columns and turn the whole thing into a dataframe, or tibble, and R tells me this won't work unless all the columns are the same length?
The issue is, the total number of rows will vary unpredictably since I'm scraping data. I need a solution that will always "trim" the data to the last real value in the column I care about, let's say "Avalue" in the toy data below. I tried filtering by "Avalue" != NA, but this led to an empty df.



Samplenumber(dbl)
Avalue(list)
Bvalue(list)




1
cat
121


2
dog
456


3
bird
12


4




5




6





Desired output would just slice off the bottom 3 rows of "Samplenumber" (4, 5, and 6), so I can then successfully unlist the rest of the dataframe.
I tried something like this but it didn't work:
       `Filter(function(x) length(x) < length('Avalue',df))
       dfclean<- df %>% map (unlist) %>% as_tibble()`


Welcome to SO, Kathleen DeBrota! This is a great first question! Especially when talking about frames with list-columns, though, I think we really need to have sample data in native form. Please [edit] your question and add the output from dput(head(df)) into a [code block]. Thanks!
